# How to use the fragments backport?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

Could somebody explain how I can use the Fragments backport? I downloaded the compatibility package with the manager, but I can't find the library that I have to link to my project to use fragments.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your SDK installation directory, you will find `extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar`. Add this to your project's `libs/` directory, and if you are an Eclipse user, also add it to your build path.

Answer (score 4):

One thing though. There is a bug in the "stock v4" android jar which is pretty annoying - you cannot receive result of any activity started from within fragments, which makes it pretty much unusable for a lot of problems. There is however a fixed version of the jar which solves the problem (until v5 is in place I guess):

http://dev.polidea.pl/ext/android-support-v4-with-onActivityResult-fix.jar

And the issue is described here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15394